# Pagination Strategies for Complex (slow) Datasets

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

What are some of the strategies being used for pagination of data sets that involve complex queries?  count(*) takes ~1.5 sec so we don't want to hit the DB for every page view.  Currently there are ~45k rows returned by this query.

Here are some of the approaches I've considered:

- Cache the row count and update it every X minutes
- Limit (and offset) the rows counted to 41 (for example) and display the page picker as "1 2 3 4 ..."; then recompute if anyone actually goes to page 4 and display "... 3 4 5 6 7 ..."
- Get the row count once and store it in the user's session
- Get rid of the page picker and just have a "Next Page" link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had to engineer a few pagination strategies using PHP and MySQL for a site that  does over a million page views a day. I persued the strategy in stages:

**Multi-column indexes** I should have done this first before attempting a materialized view.

**Generating a materialized view**. I created a cron job that did a common denormalization of the document tables I was using. I would `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE ...` and then create the new table, and rotate it in:

```
SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/ondeck.txt' FROM mytable ...;
CREATE TABLE ondeck_mytable LIKE mytable;
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/ondeck.txt' INTO TABLE ondeck_mytable...;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dugout_mytable;
RENAME TABLE atbat_mytable TO dugout_mytable, ondeck_mytable TO atbat_mytable;
```

This kept the lock time on the write contended `mytable` down to a minimum and the pagination queries could hammer away on the `atbat` materialized view. I've simplified the above, leaving out the actual manipulation, which are unimportant.

**Memcache** I then created a wrapper about my database connection to cache these paginated results into memcache. This was a huge performance win. However, it was still not good enough.

**Batch generation** I wrote a PHP daemon and extracted the pagination logic into it. It would detect changes `mytable` and periodically regenerate the from the oldest changed record to the most recent record all the pages to the webserver's filesystem. With a bit of `mod_rewrite`, I could check to see if the page existed on disk, and serve it up. This also allowed me to take effective advantage of *reverse proxying* by letting Apache detect `If-Modified-Since` headers, and respond with `304` response codes. (Obviously, I removed any option of allowing users to select the number of results per page, an unimportant feature.)

Updated:
**RE `count(*)`:** When using MyISAM tables, `COUNT` didn't create a problem when I was able to reduce the amount of read-write contention on the table. If I were doing InnoDB, I would create a trigger that updated an adjacent table with the row count. That trigger would just +1 or -1 depending on INSERT or DELETE statements.

**RE page-pickers (thumbwheels)** When I moved to agressive query caching, thumb wheel queries were also cached, and when it came to batch generating the pages, I was using temporary tables--so computing the thumbwheel was no problem. A lot of thumbwheel calculation simplified because it became a predictable filesystem pattern that actually only needed the largest page numer. The smallest page number was always 1.

**Windowed thumbweel** The example you give above for a windowed thumbwheel (<< 4 [5] 6 >>) should be pretty easy to do without any queries at all so long as you know your maximum number of pages.

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion is ask MySQL for 1 row more than you need in each query, and decide based on the number of rows in the result set whether or not to show the `next page`-link.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL has a specific mechanism to compute an approximated count of a result set without the `LIMIT` clause: [`FOUND_ROWS()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows).

Answer (score 1):

`MySQL` is quite good in optimizing `LIMIT` queries.

That means it picks appropriate join buffer, filesort buffer etc just enough to satisfy `LIMIT` clause.

Also note that with `45k` rows you probably don't need exact count. Approximate counts can be figured out using separate queries on the indexed fields. Say, this query:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    mytable
WHERE   col1 = :myvalue
        AND col2 = :othervalue
```

can be approximated by this one:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) *
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    mytable
        ) / 1000
FROM    (
        SELECT  1
        FROM    mytable
        WHERE   col1 = :myvalue
                AND col2 = :othervalue
        LIMIT 1000
        )
```

, which is much more efficient in `MyISAM`.

If you give an example of your complex query, probably I can say something more definite on how to improve its pagination.

Answer (score 0):

I'm by no means a MySQL expert, but perhaps giving up the COUNT(*) and going ahead with COUNT(id)?